# JLabels setPreferredSize changes the size of all JLabels not just the one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, layout-manager

I've managed to create most of a calendar with all of the JLabels and boxes in their proper place (if you want to see more code, just ask but too much is usually frowned upon) and I want to resize all of the boxes which represent the days in the calendar. They should be neat little squares like they are on any calendar.

When I do a

```
dayBoxNumbers[7].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
```

it resizes every single JLabel in the calendar to include the days of the week etc. and the entire thing looks absurd. There is no particular reason why I chose index 7 but the idea is to resize all of the days (1-31) and this has the same affect.

**Edited to include all code (very little can be left out to express the issue at hand)**

***TestCode.java***

```
package testpackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCode extends JFrame{

GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
int month = date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
DrawCalendar window = new DrawCalendar(date);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestCode frame = new TestCode();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setTitle("Calendar Project");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
   public TestCode(){
       setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       add(window);
   }
}
```

**DrawCalendar.java**

```
package testpackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawCalendar extends JPanel{

private JLabel[] dayBoxNumbers;
private JLabel month = new JLabel("Month");
private JLabel[] days = {
    new JLabel("Sunday"),
    new JLabel("Monday"),
    new JLabel("Tuesday"),
    new JLabel("Wednesday"),
    new JLabel("Thursday"),
    new JLabel("Friday"),
    new JLabel("Saturday")
};



private JPanel window = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
private JPanel topLabels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    private JPanel dayLabels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 7));
private JPanel dayBoxes = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,7));





public DrawCalendar(GregorianCalendar date){

    //put days and month into topLabels then add topLabels to UI
    for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++){
        dayLabels.add(days[x]);
    }

    month.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    topLabels.add(month);
    topLabels.add(dayLabels);
    window.add(topLabels, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    window.add(dayBoxes, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(window);

    //Find the grid square to start the date
    int firstDay = getFirstDay(date);
    int lastDay = date.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    addDaySquares(firstDay, lastDay);


}


private void addDaySquares(int first, int last){
    //Create blank entries into the grid
    for(int i = 1; i < first; i++){
        dayBoxes.add(new JLabel(""));   
    }

    //create array of JLabels for day boxes
    dayBoxNumbers = new JLabel[last];
    for(int x=0; x < last; x++){
        dayBoxNumbers[x] = new JLabel(String.valueOf(x+1));
    }

    //Add JLabels to the grid and edit properties
    for(int j=0; j < last; j++){
        dayBoxNumbers[j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        dayBoxNumbers[j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        dayBoxNumbers[j].setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        dayBoxNumbers[1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,40));
        dayBoxes.add(dayBoxNumbers[j]);
    }


}

private int getFirstDay(GregorianCalendar firstDay){
    firstDay.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    return firstDay.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}
}
```

Comment: A guess -- are you using GridLayout? If so, setting the size of a component can set the size of all the components. And yes, we do need to see more code and don't want to see all of it. Best to post a minimal compilable and runnable example, one we can test, modify and help correct, one that has no code unrelated to the problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I am  using a grid layout. Is there a way to set the size of each grid square in one particular element? IE only resize all the grid squares that hold the calendar days but not the grid that holds the spelled out days?  Let me put something more practical together then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me:

> A guess -- are you using GridLayout? If so, setting the size of a component can set the size of all the components. And yes, we do need to see more code and don't want to see all of it. Best to post a minimal compilable and runnable example, one we can test, modify and help correct, one that has no code unrelated to the problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

You:

> I am using a grid layout. Is there a way to set the size of each grid square in one particular element? IE only resize all the grid squares that hold the calendar days but not the grid that holds the spelled out days?

You've verified that you are in fact using GridLayout as per my guess. You will likely need to use a more complex layout including either nesting JPanels, each using its own layout, or consider using GridBagLayout or MigLayout.

For better help, consider creating and showing us your [sscce](http://sscce.org).

**Edit 2**
Yeah, you're using GridLayout for everything. Don't do that. Instead nest JPanels with other layouts. For instance the main JPanel could use a BoxLayout laying everything along the page axis, then you could have a heading JPanel that uses FlowLayout and holds the heading JLabel, a day of week JPanel that uses a GridLayout with 7 columns, and your calendar JPanel that holds the dates and uses a GridLayout.

Comment: I don't think you realize how much of a hero you are to me right now. Thank you. I've been struggling with the layouts they don't do what you'd think they should. This has been very insightful thanks agian!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize all JLabels you should use

```
if (int j=0; j<last; j++){
   dayBoxNumbers[j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,40));
}
```

you had set the size of JLabel index 1 different

```
dayBoxNumbers[1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,40)); //why this?
```

Comment: that was to show that resizing only one label by itself actually resized every label in the GUI